# using god monitoring for sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, god, sidekiq

I have been looking for the configuration on how to start sidekiq using the god monitoring system. Below is the god file i use to start sidekiq.

```
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || "/home/ubuntu/Projects/app"

God.watch do |w|
  w.dir      = "#{rails_root}"
  w.name     = "sidekiq"
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.env      = {"RAILS_ENV" => rails_env}
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.start = "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -f #{rails_root}/ sidekiq -c 25 -q worker,15 -q distributor,5"

  w.uid = 'ubuntu'

  # determine the state on startup
  w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
    end
  end

  # determine when process has finished starting
  w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end

    # failsafe
    on.condition(:tries) do |c|
      c.times = 5
      c.transition = :start
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end
  end

  # start if process is not running
  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = false
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this script using the `god` command the god server is "showing process not running" as if nothing is happening. I believe I am not calling the sidekiq using the `w.start` correctly,

I use `bundle exec sidekiq -c 25 -q worker,15 -q distributor,5` under development mode and it was working fine.

What I am I missing? Is there a different way how to deploy the sidekiq workers?

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing which solved the "process is not running" issue for me was to properly define `dir` attribute:

```
w.dir = "#{Rails.root}"
```

That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues.
Specifying queue and concurrency settings under sidekiq.yml solved it for me. In your god start,

`sidekiq -e #{env} -C #{root}/config/sidekiq.yml`

The Sidekiq Github has an example of the yml config. It goes something like:

```
---
:concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - [a, 5]
  - [b, 3]
  - [c, 2]
  - [default, 3]
```

I hope you have already found a solution though.

Answer (score -1):

I've just used your code to deploy my own god / sidekiq setup, and this change got it working for me. I replaced your `w.start` with:

`w.start = "bundle exec sidekiq -q release,1 -q artist,2 -q artists,3 -c 20"`

(Though of course those queues are just the ones I happened to use, and aren't relevant)